# Pandas How to set the date as the index, and is it a good idea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df
    Date        DestUserName    Percent
0   2019-01-01  100             1.000000
1   2019-01-01  101             1.000000
2   2019-01-01  102             1.000000
3   2019-01-01  103             1.000000
4   2019-01-02  100             1.000000
5   2019-01-02  101             0.923077
6   2019-01-02  103             0.800000
7   2019-01-02  100             1.000000
8   2019-01-03  103             0.800000
9   2019-01-03  102             1.000000
10  2019-01-03  101             1.000000
11  2019-01-04  100             1.000000
11  2019-01-04  102             1.000000
11  2019-01-04  103             0.972222


df.dtypes
Date            object 
DestUserName    object 
Percent         float64
dtype: object
```

I am looking to flip the data around so that the date(string) is either the first column or the index, the username/userid(string) is the column names and the percent(float64) is the data in the cells like the following:

```
             100       101       102       103
2019-01-01   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2019-01-02   1.000000  0.923077  NaN       0.800000
2019-01-03   NaN       1.000000  1.000000  0.800000
2019-01-04   1.000000  NaN       1.000000  0.972222
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?  I have seen this before, but is it a good idea or bad idea to store the Date(string) as the index?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a date index. You can accomplish what you need with a basic reshape operation like `pivot_table` or `unstack`. However, you have two rows with `Date=2019-01-02` and `DestUserName=100`. What do you expect to happen in this case?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates().pivot('Date','DestUserName', 'Percent')` or `df.drop_duplicates().set_index(['Date', 'DestUserName']).unstack(1)` per @IgorRaush suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment Chris left:

```
df.drop_duplicates().pivot('Date','DestUserName', 'Percent') or 
df.drop_duplicates().set_index(['Date', 'DestUserName']).unstack(1)
```